# postgresql json_build_object property LIKE

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column named `"data"` that contains `json` object of telemetry data.

The telemetry data is recieved from devices, where some of the devices has received a firmware upgrade. After the upgrade some of the properties has received a "`namespace`" (e.g. "`"propertyname"`" is now "`"dsns:propertyname"`"), and there is also a few of the properties which is suddenly camelcased (e.g. "`"propertyname"`" is now "`"propertyName"`".
Neither the meaning of the properties or the number of properties has changed.

When querying the table, I do not want to get the whole "data", as the `json` is quite large. I only want the properties that are needed.

For now I have simply used a `json_build_object` such as:

```
select json_build_object('requestedproperty',"data"-> 'requestedproperty','anotherrequestedproperty',"data"-> 'anotherrequestedproperty') as "data"
from device_data
where id ='f4ddf01fcb6f322f5f118100ea9a81432' 
and timestamp >= '2020-01-01 08:36:59.698' and timestamp <= '2022-02-16 08:36:59.698'
order by timestamp desc
```

But it does not work for fetching data from after the firmware upgrade for the devices that has received it.
It still works for querying data from before the upgrade, and I would like to have only one query for this if possible.

Are there some easy way to "ignore" namespaces and be case insensitive through `json_build_object`?

I'm obviously no postgresql expert, and would love all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of insanity is exactly why device developers should not ever be allowed anywhere near a keyboard :-)

This is not an easy fix, but so long as you know the variations on the key names, you can use `coalesce()` to accomplish your goal and update your query with each new release:

```
json_build_object(
  'requestedproperty', coalesce(
                         data->'requestedproperty',
                         data->'dsns:requestedproperty',
                         data->'requestedProperty'),
  'anotherrequestedproperty', coalesce(data-> 'anotherrequestedproperty',
                                       data-> 'dsns:anotherrequestedproperty',
                                       data-> 'anotherRequestedProperty')
) as "data"
```

Edit to add:  You can also use `jsonb_each_text()`, treat key-value pairs as rows, and then use `lower()` and a regex split to doctor key names more generally, but I bet that the kinds of scatterbrains behind the inconsistencies you already see will eventually lead to a misspelled key name someday.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, it solved my problem! :)